# How to set config file using javascript/angular.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I need one help.I want to set config file which will keep all javascript file path and in index page it will called dynamically and include using angular.js or Javascript. I am explaining my file below.

> index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="Channabasavashwara">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<title>...:::WELCOME TO Channabasavashwara Institude of Technology:::...</title>
<link href="css/pace.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/pace.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angularjs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!--<script src="js/angularroute.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->
<script src="js/angularuirouter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="controller/loginRoute.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- GLOBAL STYLES - Include these on every page. -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:300,400,500,700,300italic,400italic,500italic,700italic' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="icons/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- PAGE LEVEL PLUGIN STYLES -->
<!-- THEME STYLES - Include these on every page. -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/angular-datepicker.css" />
<link href="css/style22.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/plugins.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/load.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<div  ui-view>

</div>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.popupoverlay.js"></script>
<script src="js/shortcut.js"></script>
<script src="js/defaults.js"></script>
<script src="js/logout.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see here i have many javascript and css file links.Here i need i will set path in any other file , call them to this `index.html` and will include using Loop.Please help me.

Comment: Please explain in more detail exactly what it is you are wanting to do

Comment: @charlietfl : Let me to explain again.I have so many js/css files which has included in this index.html file.But instead of doing this ,i will have one other file where i will add only the js/css file path .In the index file those js/css files will be called and add using loop inside `<script src="path"></script>` like this.

Comment: Depends on your environment. Can use task runners like gulp in your development environment or use server language to render the page.

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you want using [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) or [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/). In case you are not using one of them yet, I suggest you to take a look at them.

For your specific case, there are several tools you can use. For example, for gulp, you can use this [gulp-inject](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject).